# FTP Request Header Format

Tags: ftp, ftpwebrequest

I want to know the difference in the ftp request header for an ipv4 server and ipv6 server.
 can anyone give the header format for those ipv4 and ipv6?

thanks in advance,
Ramulu Ponnam

Comment: What do you mean by "ftp request header", do you have a specific command in mind?

Comment: Hi Mat, my question is how a ftp request recognizes the server to process.If ,it is requesting ipv4 addressed server where it could identify that ipv4 server and how it could be differentiated to ipv6 server?                                                                In http request header , Referer and host fields modified to ipv6 server from ipv4,similarly what is the difference  in ftp?      As i know,ftp request has done in multiple steps(control connection,username,password,dataconnection..),so,in which step it could be effected and how it could be?   thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean HTTP?  FTP just sends one-line commands, not full headers like HTTP.